# How to pass the fetch data from table from one function to another function in php

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a table named as `tab2` in mysql. It contains name and phone fields.

I have created a function named as `gettabledata()`:

```
function gettabledata()
{
    $data = array();

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab2");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
     //Here I am unable to get that how can I pass the fetched data in row 
    //  variable to anywhere this function called.
 //  After update:
     return $row;
}
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{
       $gettab = createtable();//calling the function gettabledata

       //Here I want to get the all data from that table
     // After doing Update:
      foreach($gettab as $row){
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['phone'];
     }

}
```

After Update I am getting warning like:

```
`
Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in E:\xampp\htdocs\practive\csvtest.php on line 29

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in E:\xampp\htdocs\practive\csvtest.php on line 29

Warning: Illegal string offset 'phone' in E:\xampp\htdocs\practive\csvtest.php on line 30

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in E:\xampp\htdocs\practive\csvtest.php on line 30

Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in E:\xampp\htdocs\practive\csvtest.php on line 29
0
Warning: Illegal string offset 'phone' in E:\xampp\htdocs\practive\csvtest.php on line 30 `
```

Also on doing `print_r($gettab)`, I got:

```
Array ( [name] => [phone] => 0 )
```

Its just first record from table.

Help me with this.Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a return statement at the end of the

> gettabledata()

Modify the function with return statement as follows.

```
    function gettabledata()
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tab2");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        return $row;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['action']))
    {
         $row_arr = gettabledata();//calling the function gettabledata

         foreach($row_arr as $row){
            echo $row['id'];
         }

     }
```

Comment: No not working, its just returning first record @Udara Seneviratne

Comment: @MohammedSabir Can you please update your question with how you verified it just returning the first record.

Comment: @MohammedSabir return of gettabledata() is an array. So, you need to loop the array. I updated my answer with that part.

Comment: Please check I modify after doing update as per your instruction. @Udara Seneviratne

Comment: @MohammedSabir Can you please add // before the comment lines. That will make more clear your question

Comment: added @Udara Seneviratne